# Is the ListObjectsV2 api call implemented in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, compatibility

I am using the [aws go sdk `ListObjectsV2` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjectsV2), and I get back a response like this:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message><Details>Invalid query parameter(s): [list-type, start-after]</Details></Error>`

From what I see in [the `List Objects` docs for GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-bucket-list), these parameters are not included.

If this was a known limitation, I would have expected it to be listed in [the `Simple Migration` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not currently support the ListObjectsV2 API.

The feature request is being tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155109631).

Comment: Awesome, thanks jterrace. I'll accept that answer as authoritative since you work at Google.

Comment: To your knowledge, are there any plans to add support for this API in the future?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not allowed to share any information that's not already public.

Comment: OK sure, I understand. I wasn't sure how public you guys were about plans. Thanks for the information you did provide!

Comment: Do you know if the AWS compatibility API for GCS supports [bulk deletes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html)?  That's another one we're having problems with.

Comment: Is there any alternative way available to this for GCP? I want to list objects available in the GCP bucket.

Comment: It's been years and nothing changed... Is there anywhere we can "vote" or otherwise kindly inquire about implementing the ListObjectsV2 API?

Comment: @DaviSEvangelista added a link to the public issue for the feature request